# Headless Chromium with Puppeteer doesn't work on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, headless-browser

Help!

Sorry for my bad english

Issue:Applying the  Puppeteer from the AWS linux AMI doesn't work.

Thrown error:

```
(node:11529) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
/home/admin/nodejs/crawlV1/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-575458/chrome-linux/chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_add_instance_private
[1024/070208.617341:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Hope everybody help please.

Comment: Could you walk me through your installation of Puppeteer? Did you install Chrome dependencies? Pleas post your steps that got you to that error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/807)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EC2 which run Amazon Linux, and you'd like to try Google's Puppeteer (Chrome Headless), below's tutorial verified on a  EC2 instance run the latest Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09.

Try this [link](https://mockingbot.com/posts/run-puppeteer-chrome-headless-on-ec2-amazon-linux). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install and run puppeteer correctly installing this
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm